# How to surround code by curly braces in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, curly-braces

How to surround code by curly braces in IntelliJ IDEA? Is there any keyboard-shortcut for such operation?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Surround With), then <kbd>A</kbd> (Curly Braces).

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac, couldn't find "curly braces" after doing option+command+T

Comment: @ZinanXing, It's B on Mac

Comment: On Mac ⌘Command+Option+T brings up a menu, hit A to select curly braces option

Answer (score 129):

Just configure Smart Keys as follow:
`IDE Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Surround selection on typing quote or brace`.

[image]

From the IntelliJ built-in help:

> If this check box is **selected**, the selected text on typing a quote,
> double-quote or brace, will be surrounded with these characters.
>
> If this check box is **not selected**, then the typed quotes, double-quotes
> or braces will replace the selection.

Comment: Bless you!

NB to others: By default, my curly brackets are showing up on the left margin. You may have to play a bit with exactly what you have selected and then use the autoindent feature to make this technique result in code you like the look of.

Comment: Saw the option, but I've no idea how to use this.

Comment: me neither... when I select an expression and type "brace" it writes braces and cannot resolve that...

Comment: Anyone wondering how to use it : select you text and type curly braces(or double quote) and the selection would be placed inside a curly brace.

Comment: @xetra11  Do not type the word "brace". Type the character for an opening brace: "{"  while having a text selected.

Answer (score 6):

I had oneline if statement without curly braces and I had to update it with braces in whole file. So I updated code style to always add braces for if/else statement.
In Idea go to:

> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces (tab)

Find *"'If()' Statement"/"Force braces"* and change value from **"Do not force"**(default) to **"Always"**.
Press `ctrl + alt + L` to reformat your file and curly braces would be added.
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc9iC.png)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is, ***select the code part*** that you want and **press** **`Shift + [`**

Answer (score 5):

Just click as the below 2 steps

1, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
 2, then press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> at the same time.

Hope to help you.

Comment: Typo in first step, shall be `CTRL+ALT+T`

Answer (score 5):

Add "Control flow statement without braces" to inspection settings. Then run inspection, select them in the list and then select "Apply Fix 'Add braces'".

It just saved me a whole days tedious work!

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a live template first. Just go Preferences and add a template to html/xml[image]

[image]

Comment: Can an arbitrary shortcut be assigned to this, say `Command + B`?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just follow the arrows in this picture, from left to right:
[image: Screenshot with arrows]